# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialize')

Tags: angular

I'm getting above error when i called the registerListener() function in my component ts file.

listerners.service.ts file

```
 eventRegistry: object = {};
  constructor() { }
  createListener(module: string, event: string, initialValue: any) {
    if (!this.eventRegistry[module]) {
      this.eventRegistry[module] = {};
    }
    if (!this.eventRegistry[module][event]) {
      this.eventRegistry[module][event] = { "initialValue": initialValue, "listeners": [] };
    } else {
      alert("event " + module + "::" + event + " is already created");
    }
  }
  registerListener(module: string, event: string, callback: CallableFunction) {
    debugger
    if (!this.eventRegistry[module][event]) {
  
      alert("event " + module + "::" + event + " is not created so far.");
    }
    this.eventRegistry[module][event]["listeners"].push(callback);
  }
  callListener(module: string, event: string, obj: any) {
    if (!this.eventRegistry[module]) {
      alert("event " + module + "::" + event + " is not created, module does not exist");
    }
    if (this.eventRegistry[module][event]) {

      let initialValue: any = this.eventRegistry[module][event]["initialValue"];

      for (let i = 0; i < this.eventRegistry[module][event]["listeners"].length; i++) {
        initialValue = this.eventRegistry[module][event]["listeners"][i](initialValue, obj);
      }
      return initialValue;
    } else {
      alert("event " + module + "::" + event + " is not created");
    }
  }
```

I'm calling above function in flight component ts file

```
public router:Router, private listenerService: ListenersService) {
      listenerService.registerListener("shell","initialize",function(value,obj) {
        debugger
        console.log(value +""+ obj);
      });

      listenerService.callListener("shell","initialize",{});
     }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUvZM.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your `registerListener` function you do the following:

```
if (!this.eventRegistry[module][event]) {
  alert('event ' + module + '::' + event + ' is not created so far.');
}
```

When you call this function like this:

```
listenerService.registerListener('shell', 'initialize', function (value, obj) {...})
```

This means that when you call `registerListener` with parameters `shell` and `initialize` you essentially look inside `this.eventRegistry.shell` to check if `initialize` exists.

The error you're getting tells you your script cannot read `initialize` from `undefined`. Which basically means that `this.eventRegistry.shell` is `undefined`, thus it does not exist.

What you probably want to do is add a `?` operator in your `if` statement to check if each element exists. Like this:

```
if (!this.eventRegistry?.[module]?.[event]) {
```

Adding this will also check if `this.eventRegistry` is `true-ish`, (meaning it contains a value other than `undefined, null, or 0`. It will do the same for `[module]`.

I hope this answers your question where your `undefined` comes from.